# Como organizar o Diretório do Tema

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc

Estou com uma duvida de como dividir os arquivos `CSS` e `Javascript` no meu diretório do meu projeto `ASP.NET`

Adquiri o tema `METRONIC`, o diretório do tema possui uma pasta onde fica todos os arquivos `css` e `js` chamada de "*assets*".

**Exemplo css:**

```
<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,600,700&subset=all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="../assets/global/plugins/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="../assets/global/plugins/simple-line-icons/simple-line-icons.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="../assets/global/plugins/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="../assets/global/plugins/bootstrap-switch/css/bootstrap-switch.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<!-- END GLOBAL MANDATORY STYLES -->
<!-- BEGIN PAGE LEVEL PLUGIN STYLES -->
<link href="../assets/global/plugins/gritter/css/jquery.gritter.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="../assets/global/plugins/bootstrap-daterangepicker/daterangepicker-bs3.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="../assets/global/plugins/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="../assets/global/plugins/jqvmap/jqvmap/jqvmap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<!-- END PAGE LEVEL PLUGIN STYLES -->
```

**Exemplo JS:**

```
<script src="../assets/global/plugins/jquery-slimscroll/jquery.slimscroll.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../assets/global/plugins/jquery.blockui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../assets/global/plugins/jquery.cokie.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../assets/global/plugins/bootstrap-switch/js/bootstrap-switch.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!-- END CORE PLUGINS -->
<!-- BEGIN PAGE LEVEL PLUGINS -->
<script src="../assets/global/plugins/jqvmap/jqvmap/jquery.vmap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../assets/global/plugins/jqvmap/jqvmap/maps/jquery.vmap.russia.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../assets/global/plugins/jqvmap/jqvmap/maps/jquery.vmap.world.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../assets/global/plugins/jqvmap/jqvmap/maps/jquery.vmap.europe.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../assets/global/plugins/jqvmap/jqvmap/maps/jquery.vmap.germany.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../assets/global/plugins/jqvmap/jqvmap/maps/jquery.vmap.usa.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../assets/global/plugins/jqvmap/jqvmap/data/jquery.vmap.sampledata.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Então como eu deveria separar eles? pois todos estão na mesma pasta. Devo colocar cada arquivo `css` na pasta `CONTENT` e o `JS` na pasta `SCRIPTS`?

Ou posso colocar só a pasta `ASSENT` dentro do `content` e apontar tudo para ela?

*OBS: a duvida é básica mas não queria começar o projeto de maneira errada*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A localização dos seus `scripts`/`styles` é algo bem pessoal, você pode colocar estes arquivos na pasta `Script`/`Content` ou em alguma pasta reservada para os `frameworks` e `blibiotecas` de terceiros.

Eu particularmente colocaria a pasta `assets` dentro de `~/lib/metronic/assets/...`, assim como eu faria com outras blibiotecas e frameworks, como o `Bootstrap`, `jQuery`, etc... como no exemplo abaixo.:

- bootstrap -> `~/lib/bootstrap-sass/assets/...`
- jQuery -> `~/lib/jquery/src/...`

Ou seja, de forma geral, organizo os as blibiotecas que utilizo em `~/lib/{nome_da_blibioteca}/{arquivos_da_blibioteca}/...`, ja à pasta `Content` e `Scrypt`, eu reservaria apenas para os `scripts` e `styles` de minha autoria.

Um outro ponto, tente utilizar alguma ferramenta para `minificar` e `unificar` os seus `scripts` e `styles`, você pode começar utilizando o [`Microsoft Optimization Framework`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization/) por ser mais simples, para saber mais veja o seguinte Guia.: [`Bundling and Minification`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/performance/bundling-and-minification).

Já no meu caso, eu utilizo o `Gulp` para `minificar`, `unificar` e `transpilar` (no caso de utilizar o `TypeScript` e `SCSS`).